# insert anonymous hash into anonymous hash for counting in a loop

Tags: perl, hash

I'm trying to count starts and stops of some services i keep track of in logs. 
I'm not going to past here entire code, but my way of doing hash is this:
 I'm passing those starts and stops into anonymous hash .
 First I'm creating anonymous hash  filled with keys and values (in my case $knot is a key an zeros are values). Next im replaqcing values with another hash.
My code looks like this:

```
foreach $knot (@knots){ 
        chomp $knot;
        $variable = $variable."$knot;0;";

        $Services = {split(/;/,$variable)};
}

 my $data =
    {
            Starts=>'0',
            Stops=>'0',
    };  

foreach my $key (keys %$Services) {
           $Services->{$key} = $data; 
}
print Dumper $Services;
```

Printing shows:

```
$VAR1 = {
      ' knot1' => {
                      'Stops' => '0',
                      'Starts' => '0'
                    },
      ' knot2' => $VAR1->{' knot1'},
      ' knot3' => $VAR1->{' knot1'},
      ' knot4' => $VAR1->{' knot1'},
      ' knot5' => $VAR1->{' knot1'},
```

and so on. Is there a better way of doing this? My way if i'm correct is badly written because changing knot1 starts/stops changes every other knot values.

Comment: You are only ever assigning the same reference `$data`. The easiest approach to make them different between each other is to move `my $data = ...; ` into the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting is very simple in Perl, thanks to Autovivification. You can just create anonymous data structures on the fly, like so:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = ();

$hash{apple}{green}++;
$hash{apple}{red}  ++;
$hash{pear}{yellow}++;
$hash{apple}{green}++;
$hash{apple}{red}  ++;
$hash{apple}{green}++;

print Dumper(\%hash);
```

This will produce the desired structure for counting:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'apple' => {
                       'green' => 3,
                       'red' => 2
                     },
          'pear' => {
                      'yellow' => 1
                    }
        };
```

This also works in loops using variables (here using a reference to a hash):

```
my $hash_ref = {};
for my $fruit (qw( apple pear apple peach apple pear )) {
    $hash_ref->{$fruit}++;
}
print Dumper($hash_ref);
```

resulting in:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'peach' => 1,
          'pear' => 2,
          'apple' => 3
        };
```

Comment: `my %hash = ();` is equivalent to `my %hash; %hash = ();`, which is redundant because `my` already creates the hash empty.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful , i have made loop with added your code and it works like a charm :)

Comment: @MarcinK nice! Glad I could be of help. Could you please accept the answer as your valid answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of this answer. This will help you, me and all the other stack users. thx

Comment: @Boris Däppen Done :)